# Can never change my subscription

Tags: ubuntu-one

Every time I log into Ubuntu One there is a message telling me that no account changes can be made while the system is updating which can take 2 hours. So I am NEVER able to modify anything. This bugs me because I am paying for the service and now I have no control over the payment process or what I want to do.

What gives?

Comment: You need to contact Ubuntu One support with your issue. https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/